# if button clicked for 4 times, I could show Interstitial?

Tags: android

I installed Interstitial ad in Detailactivity, but I must if button clicked for 4 times show Interstitial ad? Is this possible? I mean look at this;

> DetailActivity

```
private View.OnClickListener onFabButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (future == null) {
                //prepare the call
                future = Ion.with(DetailActivity.this)
                        .load(mSelectedImage.getHighResImage(mWallpaperWidth, mWallpaperHeight))
                        .progressHandler(progressCallback)
                        .asInputStream();
                if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                    mInterstitialAd.show();

                animateStart();

                mFabButton.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_LONG).setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        streamAndSetImage();
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        streamAndSetImage();
                        super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
                    }
                }).start();
            } else {
                animateReset(false);
            }
        }
    };
```

Please look at this new DetailActivity

> Edited DetailActivity

```
 int counter = 0;
    private View.OnClickListener onFabButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (counter == 4) {
                /** SHOW AD **/
                if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                /** RESET THE COUNTER **/
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                /** INCREMENT THE COUNTER **/
                counter++;

                /** DO SOMETHING ELSE **/

            }
            if (future == null) {
                //prepare the call
                future = Ion.with(DetailActivity.this)
                        .load(mSelectedImage.getHighResImage(mWallpaperWidth, mWallpaperHeight))
                        .progressHandler(progressCallback)
                        .asInputStream();


                animateStart();

                mFabButton.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_LONG).setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        streamAndSetImage();
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        streamAndSetImage();
                        super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
                    }
                }).start();
            } else {
                animateReset(false);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Sure. Store a counter (and integer) initializing it with **0**. Increment it every-time the button is clicked. When the counter value reaches **4**, show the ad and reset the counter to **0**.

Comment: But I don't know. Please write in code? (I'm beginner.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this. It's untested of course, but the logic should be useful:

```
int counter = 0;

private View.OnClickListener onFabButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter == 4) {
                /** SHOW AD **/

               /** RESET THE COUNTER **/
               counter = 0;
            } else {
                /** INCREMENT THE COUNTER **/
                counter++;

               /** DO SOMETHING ELSE **/
               // MOVE THIS BLOCK INSIDE THE ELSE BLOCK AS ILLUSTRATED
                if (future == null) {
                    //prepare the call
                    future = Ion.with(DetailActivity.this)
                        .load(mSelectedImage.getHighResImage(mWallpaperWidth, mWallpaperHeight))
                        .progressHandler(progressCallback)
                        .asInputStream();


                    animateStart();

                    mFabButton.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_LONG).setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            streamAndSetImage();
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            streamAndSetImage();
                            super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
                        }
                    }).start();
                } else {
                    animateReset(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Additionally, you could store the `counter` value using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) so the number of *clicks* can be stored in between app use *sessions*.

Comment: Oh very awesome! Thank you for your details.

Comment: @UfukCampus: Glad to have been of help. Good luck with your development. :-)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: Ha ha ha. This really was a simple one. On a side note, using `++` to increment an integer is simpler. ;-)

Comment: @IceMAN Sir , Indeed indeed .

Comment: @UfukCampus: Can you update your OP with the new code? Let's see if we can fix that.

Comment: Please Look at this video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jrB7MbTdX-ZkNpMmoydDhPRm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @UfukCampus: Check the edit. Basically, move the `if (future == null) {....` part where it reads `/** DO SOMETHING ELSE **/` and see if that works.

Comment: Sir, if I select other image  counter say  = 0, I mean don't work. But I stay in same image, click the button 4 times then it work.

Comment: @UfukCampus: While the logic is correct, there must be a problem in the implementation. Post your entire activity code. Not just the click listener.

Comment: @UfukCampus: Are you inflating a `RecyclerView` that I don't see? If clicking the button on a single image shows the Ad, then there is something I am missing in your code.

Comment: No,  I use fragment activity. I dont understand.

Comment: Place this `Log.e("COUNTER", String.valueOf(counter));` before the `if (counter == 4) {` and see what it prints when you click on the button.

Comment: Okey, I look other images always E/COUNTER: 0. 
I want to count resume on other images.

Comment: Okay. Declare the `int counter = 0;` globally. Move it where you have the `private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;` declared. I think that should do it.

Comment: I tried but same wrong. If I look other images, I will see counter:0

Comment: @UfukCampus then there some other issue at hand. The logic is perfect but because I don't understand the code in it's entirety, it's hard for me to pinpoint what is causing the problem and what will fix it. But play around with it. As I said, nothing wrong with the logic here.

Comment: Okey, I will try something new.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I may problem solved. First add If int counter = 0; before  "private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd" always counter = 0. Because I need last count number. So, I passed another picture counter always resetting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this .

```
int Buttonclickcount=0; // You can declare this as global

private View.OnClickListener onFabButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Buttonclickcount++; // Increment +1

                if(Buttonclickcount==4)   // Count==4
                {
                    // Do Your Staff //
                   Log.d("Tag Name", "Click 4 times").
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do Your Staff //
                    Log.d("Tag Name", "Click n times").

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @UfukCampus what returns ?? Print this in if condition  `Log.d("Tag Name", "If").` & say .

Comment: Wait I am recording screen.

Comment: Please look at this video; https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jrB7MbTdX-ZkNpMmoydDhPRm8/view?usp=sharing