# How to Show Admob Interstitials on Counted Click?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to something like this:
[if button clicked for 4 times, I could show Interstitial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809985/if-button-clicked-for-4-times-i-could-show-interstitial)

However i couldn't make it happen.

Created a game object.
Attached script to that object.
Created a restart button.
Implemented this object on that button with onclick-runtime only etc.

Now every time user clicks restart button, interstitial ads show itself. but of course as you might know, it is very annoying.

I dont know how to count how many times users press the restart button and for example show the ads every 3 or 4 times if user press the button.

Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public string InterstitialId;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Request Ads
        //RequestBanner();
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    public void showInterstitialAd()
    {
        //Show Ad
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string adUnitId = InterstitialId;

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you idea ,you can use time class to know  last showed ad or use variable saying like every 4 game show ad on restart button click.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdScript : MonoBehaviou
{
int counter =0;
InterstitialAd interstitial;

public string InterstitialId;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
//Request Ads
//RequestBanner();
RequestInterstitial();
}

public void showInterstitialAd()
{
    counter ++;
    if(counter%4==0)
    {
    //Show Ad
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
           interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}

private void RequestInterstitial()
{
    string adUnitId = InterstitialId;

    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}
```

}

Comment: i would be grateful if you could show what I should type.